# how to response body as T in rust rocket response

Tags: rust

I am learning using rust to write a http web api. Now I define the response like this:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub struct ApiResponse {
    pub body: String,
    pub statusCode: String,
    pub resultCode: String
}
```

because every api return different entity. So I want to optimize the response body as return `T`. I tweak my code like this:

```
use rocket::serde::Deserialize;
use rocket::serde::Serialize;
use rocket::response::Responder;
use rocket::{Request, Response};
use rocket::http::{Status, ContentType};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub struct ApiResponse<T> {
    pub body: T,
    pub statusCode: String,
    pub resultCode: String
}

impl<'r,T> Responder<'r,'r> for ApiResponse<T> {
    fn respond_to(self, req: &Request) -> Result<Response<'r>, Status> {
        Response::build_from(self.body.respond_to(req).unwrap())
            .header(ContentType::JSON)
            .ok()
    }
}

impl<T> Default for ApiResponse<T>{
    fn default() -> Self {
        ApiResponse{
            body: T,
            statusCode: "200".to_string(),
            resultCode: "200".to_string()
        }
    }
}
```

but the compiler tell me error:

```
error[E0423]: expected value, found type parameter `T`
  --> src/biz/music/../../model/response/api_response.rs:26:19
   |
26 |             body: T,
   |                   ^ not a value

error[E0423]: expected value, found type parameter `T`
  --> src/biz/user/../../model/response/api_response.rs:26:19
   |
26 |             body: T,
   |                   ^ not a value
```

what should I do to fix it?

Comment: You should put constraint on `T` to be a `Default`, then `body: Default::default(),` should do

Comment: I mean, the compiler is right. `T` is a type parameter, not a value. What you probably want is something like `impl<T: Default> Default for ApiResponse<T> { ... body: Default::default() }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement Default like this:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub struct ApiResponse<T> {
    pub body: T,
    pub statusCode: String,
    pub resultCode: String
}

impl<T> Default for ApiResponse<T> where T: Default {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self{
            body: T::default(),
            statusCode: String::from("200"),
            resultCode: String::from("200")
        }
    }
}

fn main() {

    let o = ApiResponse::<i32>{body: 25, statusCode: String::from("200"), resultCode: String::from("400")};
    let b = ApiResponse::<String>::default();
    
    println!("Success {:?} {:?}", o, b);
}
```